# Specificially assign css of Jquery-UI for select elements?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui

I have a

```
<div class="advancedSearchContainer findorders">
```

within which I am specifically using some jquery-ui features - datepicker etc. Now the color that it is displaying of the default jquery-ui theme within the rails app. I can't change the default jquery-ui css file, because other parts of the site are using it.

But I want to specify the css of this feature differently, so I tried my hand at this.

```
.advancedSearchContainer .ui-state-active,
.advancedSearchContainer .ui-widget-content .ui-state-active,
.advancedSearchContainer .ui-widget-header .ui-state-active {
    border: 1px solid #acdd4a;
    background: #6eac2c url(images/ui-bg_gloss-wave_50_6eac2c_500x100.png) 50% 50% repeat-x;
    font-weight: normal;
    color: #ffffff;
}
```

But this isn't changing the colors. Any particular reason where I went wrong?

Comment: are you including these styles after the original styles are defined?  also are you qualifying the selector to a deeper state than the original css? You have a better chance of overriding the style by giving the div an id and using #advancedSearchContainer .ui-state-active

Answer (score 0):

add a body class and use the body.yourClass .advancedSearchContainer .ui-state-active,
body.yourClass .advancedSearchContainer .ui-widget-content .ui-state-active,
body.yourClass .advancedSearchContainer .ui-widget-header .ui-state-active {}

this would overrule the other css statements